# Check if bluetooth is active on Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there a programmatically way to check **if Bluetooth is active** on an Android device?

To know if the Location is enabled it's like this:

```
if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
{
    //Location not active!
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can just check the adapter state :

```c
public void EnableIfNeeded(BluetoothAdapter adapter)
 {
     if (!adapter.IsEnabled)
     {
         adapter.Enable();
     }
 }
```